# How to set multiple OnSwipe Add Android MotionLayout Single Transition?

Tags: android

I'm using android motion layout. I want to add two `OnSwipe` nodes to a single `transition`, but I don't know how. The screen I want to implement is as follows.

The screen has `ImageView` and `RecyclerView`, and `ImageView` is on top of `RecyclerView`.
There are three states of `small`, `medium`, and `full`.

- In small, only ImageView exists at the bottom of the screen, and RecyclerView is not visible.
- In medum, ImageView is located in the center of the screen, and RecyclerView is visible in the lower space.
- In full, the ImageView is located at the top of the screen, and the RecyclerView is visible in the lower space.

I want to do a transition using both an ImageView and a RecyclerView. In particular, I would like to implement the RecyclerView to transition when scrolling is not possible (the scroll position is at the top or the bottom) and when scrolling in the impossible scroll direction. How can we do that?

this is motion scene

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/medium"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/small">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:onTouchUp="autoComplete"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/header" />
    </Transition>


    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/full"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/medium">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:onTouchUp="autoComplete"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/header" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/small">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/medium">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/medium_top"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/full">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

and this activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/scrollable_header_above_recycler_view_scene">

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/medium_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: The docs say "with each `<onSwipe>` specifying a different swipe direction", but you are specifying the same direction.

Comment: Ah, then, is there any way to add an OnSwipe node with different touchAnchorId to single Transition?

Comment: Please update your question and re-enter your code as a text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of MotionLayout/OnSwipe support for NestedScrollView.

You can only automatically operate on one transition with a RecyclerView (NestedScrollView)

You have two choices:

1. Make the intermediate step using KeyFrames
2. Disable the automatic handling and manually control the transitions by listening to the scroll position.

In your case I would do the KeyFrame i.e. One Transition from small to full.
With one KeyPosition defining the position of the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I opted for the second method, and although the code got a bit messy, I got the desired behavior.